# How can I set default value in text box in magento admin custom form

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have create a field English video and save to data in database but I can't set value in edit time

I have used this code for set value.

```
$fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('ultimate_option')->__('English Video'),
            'id'  => 'option_english',
            'name'      => 'option_english',
            'after_element_html' => '<table id="modulename_tbl_data_English" cellspacing="0">
                                <button id="English" class="add" type="button" title="Add"><span><span><span>Add</span></span></span></button>
                                </table>',
            'value'  => 'hello !!'         
        ));
```

but getting this blank result

[image]

How can I set value for English text box at edit time.

Comment: can you show your full `Form.php` file?

Comment: @meenakshi I am using umc extension for create module I need multiple field for add video so I add this field extra by hardcode and save to db by insert query but in edit time i want to set value but I am unable to set normal value to this field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have after the form definitions something like this:

```
$form->setData($data);
```

or

```
$form->addData($data);
```

If you do, add this line above it:

```
if (!isset($data['option_english'])) {
    $data['option_english'] = 'Your default value here';
}
```

Comment: Where I use this code ?

Comment: In the same class, same method. After defining the form. If you don't have the line `$form->setData($data);` or `$form->addData($data);` add it and before it add the rest of the code I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in the code you might have called

```
$form->setValues($somethingHere);
```

Replace that line with:

```
$form->addValues(array('option_english'=> 'default_Value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking and are working on 1.9 and have the below

```
if($model){
    $form->setValues($model->getData());
}
```

You can do the following without having to edit your existing data, just above that code place:

```
if($model->getData('fieldName') == ""){
    $model->setData('fieldName', "yourValue");
}
```

Of course you can check isset and such but here is the basic version of setting defaults.